# uploading a file before any build job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

My requirement is to ask the user to upload a file in Jenkins (Through UI) and then Jenkins is going to perform some build jobs taking input from the file

I have tried to use file parameter in my paramterized build job , I do not have any SCM plugin , all my SVN jobs are through svn client as part of shell script

Problem is the file parameter is uploading the file only after my build steps are getting performed,as a result build step is not able to read the data from the file, is there any way to force the file upload before the build step

Comment: I tried creating a new project with file parameter and it seems to be working fine. Can you double check your Jenkins job configuration? Is it a huge file?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Step 3:

[image]

Step 4:
[image]

Comment: Yeas the file is pretty huge 400 MB

Comment: Is is possible to post your build step, after scrubbing important information?